# android app email queue

Tags: android, email-client

I've coded an Android App to use for sending email about some products. Now I would create a queue of ones everytime network is down and I can't send those ones. Can I store email into some folder? Have you a suggestions?
Thank in advance

Answer (score -1):

> Can I store email into some folder?

You can store any files you want on [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) or [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), as you see fit.

Comment: @ClaudioPomo: So convert the object into a file (e.g., JSON, XML), or store its contents in a database, or something.